# retrieving data from an API using curl/httr in R :400 bad request

Tags: json, r, post, rcurl, httr

I'm trying to fetch data in R from a web API (infermedia, to be specific)

the GET request in my case gets processed successfully. however, there are issues with POST

The requests contain data, which gets processed and is then returned. both of these are in json format.

example code from the api documentation looks like:

```
    curl -v -X GET "https://api.infermedica.com/v2/symptoms"
```

to execute this in R using curl, I use:

```
    h <- new_handle()
    handle_setheaders(h, 'app_id' = "id", 'app_key' = "key", 'Accept' = "application/json" )
    curl_fetch_memory("https://api.infermedica.com/v2/symptoms", handle = h)
```

this worked well to only send headers. However, for complex requests such as POST body, I thought I'd be better off using httr, I couldn't find a way to send body data using just curl

the same query executed using httr looks like:

```
    GET(url = "https://api.infermedica.com/v2/symptoms", verbose(),add_headers(app_id = "id", app_key = "key", 'Accept' = "application/json"))
```

this also worked. So then comes the POST request

the documentation code for data containing json looks like:

```
    curl -v -X POST -H "Content-Type:application/json" "https://api.infermedica.com/v1/diagnosis" -d '{"sex": "male", "age": 29, "evidence": [ { "id": "s_21", "choice_id": "present" } ] }'
```

for which, i created my json like this:

```
    bod <- list(sex = jsonlite::unbox('male'), age = jsonlite::unbox('26'), evidence = data.frame(id = "s_21", choice_id = 'present'))
```

if you notice, the *evidence* info is created as a data frame. The reason for this is that when I change it to json, it looks exactly like the text json from documentation. Here's what I mean:

```
    POST(url = "https://api.infermedica.com/v1/diagnosis", body = bod  ,
      encode = 'json', verbose(),
     add_headers(app_id = "id", app_key = "key", 'Content-Type:' = "application/json"))
```

the verbose for this request is:

- POST /v1/diagnosis HTTP/1.1

  - Host: api.infermedica.com
  - User-Agent: libcurl/7.47.0 r-curl/1.2 httr/1.2.1
  - Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
  - Accept: application/json, text/xml, application/xml, */*
  - Content-Type: application/json
  - app_id: id
  - app_key: key
  - Content-Type:: application/json
  - Content-Length: 74
  - {"sex":"male","age":"26","evidence":[{"id":"s_21","choice_id":"present"}]}
  - HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
  - Date: Tue, 20 Sep 2016 13:26:46 GMT
  - Content-Type: application/json;charset=utf-8
  - Content-Length: 25
  - Connection: keep-alive
  - X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
  - X-Frame-Options: sameorigin
  - Server: Infermedica
  - Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
  - Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
  - Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, OPTIONS
  - Access-Control-Allow-Headers: DNT,X-Mx-ReqToken,Keep-Alive,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type,app_id,app_key

see the line with the body data:-

{"sex":"male","age":"26","evidence":[{"id":"s_21","choice_id":"present"}]}

exactly how the api dictates it should look like.

But, but, the bad request error is thrown upon me.
I tried using a nested list for body, which didn't do any good. Copy-pasting the json string from the documentation page and passing it as-it-is also yields the same error.
The request does gets processed when i run the cURL command from terminal, of course, which means there's something wrong in the way I'm passing the json data to the server

Any help will be greatly appreciated

Comment: Your problem is:  `age = jsonlite::unbox('26')` you're passing a string where the API waits for a number (your curl json has an unquoted 26). Remove the quotes around 26 and you should be OK.

Comment: @Tensibai I've tried that as well, and unfortunately, it still throws the same error upon me

Comment: you have two times the content-type header also. Try removing it from the add_header call

Comment: hey @Tensibai, removing the content type header information did the trick!, It's a 200-a-okay :D many thanks to you.
however, you say I have it two times? I don't understand, it was passed only once per request

Comment: Check your verbose output, you have one before the app_id header and on just before the json data. And this makes the server receiving the request to find it as a bad request :) This is due to the encode="json" and the manual header you added in the add_headers call.

Comment: ah yes, it's right there. I should learn to pay more attention to logs in general. Thank you, again.

Answer (score 2):

This may help get you started:

```
library(httr)
library(jsonlite)
library(dplyr)

im_info <- function() {

  res <- GET("https://api.infermedica.com/v2/info",
             add_headers(app_id=Sys.getenv("INFERMEDICA_APP_ID"),
                         app_key=Sys.getenv("INFERMEDICA_APP_KEY")))

  stop_for_status(res)

  content(res, as="text", encoding="UTF-8") %>% 
    fromJSON(flatten=TRUE)

}


im_list_symptoms <- function() {

  res <- GET("https://api.infermedica.com/v2/symptoms",
             add_headers(app_id=Sys.getenv("INFERMEDICA_APP_ID"),
                         app_key=Sys.getenv("INFERMEDICA_APP_KEY")))

  stop_for_status(res)

  content(res, as="text", encoding="UTF-8") %>% 
    fromJSON(flatten=TRUE)

}

im_get_symptom <- function(symptom_id="s_277") {

  res <- GET(sprintf("https://api.infermedica.com/v2/symptoms/%s", symptom_id),
             add_headers(app_id=Sys.getenv("INFERMEDICA_APP_ID"),
                         app_key=Sys.getenv("INFERMEDICA_APP_KEY")))

  stop_for_status(res)

  content(res, as="text", encoding="UTF-8") %>% 
    fromJSON(flatten=TRUE)

}


im_start_diagnosis <- function() {
  return(list(age=NULL, sex=NULL))
}

im_add_patient_info <- function(diag_obj, age, sex) {
  diag_obj$age <- unbox(as.numeric(age))
  diag_obj$sex <- unbox(sex)
  diag_obj
}

im_add_evidence <- function(diag_obj, id, choice=c('present', 'absent', 'unknown')) {

  choice <- match.arg(choice, c('present', 'absent', 'unknown'))

  df <- data_frame(id=id, choice_id=choice)

  if (length(diag_obj$evidence) == 0) {
    diag_obj$evidence <- df
  } else {
    bind_rows(diag_obj$evidence, df)
  }

  diag_obj

}

im_get_diagnosis <- function(diag_obj) {

  res <- POST("https://api.infermedica.com/v2/diagnosis",
              add_headers(app_id=Sys.getenv("INFERMEDICA_APP_ID"),
                          app_key=Sys.getenv("INFERMEDICA_APP_KEY")),
              body=diag_obj,
              encode="json",
              verbose())

  stop_for_status(res)

  content(res, as="text", encoding="UTF-8") %>% 
    fromJSON(flatten=TRUE)

}

im_start_diagnosis() %>% 
  im_add_patient_info(29, "male") %>% 
  im_add_evidence("s_21", "present") %>% 
  im_get_diagnosis()
```

You can now use an alpha package for this: [`infermedica`](https://gitlab.com/hrbrmstr/infermedica)